# Django encoding issue on ubuntu server

Tags: python, django, api, utf-8, django-rest-framework

I am working on Django Rest Framework and I have a simple login view.py and everything is working perfectly fine on my localhost. But on ubuntu server it throws some strange error.

Following is the view class

```
class userDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    header = Header(request)
    checkHeader = header.checkHeader()

    if checkHeader['status'] == 0:
        return Response(checkHeader, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    # platform = request.META.get('HTTP_PLATFORM', 'Not Found')
    data = request.data
    serializer = loginSerializer(data = data)        
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        data = serializer.data
        username = data['username']
        password = data['pword']
        authenticate = Authentication(username, password)
        loginData = authenticate.check()
        if loginData[0]['status'] == 1:
            auth = skAuth_Token(loginData[0]['userID'])
            auth_token = auth.encode()
            if auth.saveToken(auth_token):
                rowData = UserMaster.objects.get(pk=loginData[0]['userID'])
                dataSerializer = loginDataSerializer(rowData)
                response = {
                    'status': 1,
                    'message': 'Login Successfull',
                    'header': checkHeader,
                    'skAuth_Token': auth_token,
                    'data': dataSerializer.data
                }
            else:
                response = {
                    'status': 0,
                    'message': 'Couldnot save skAuth_Token in dB',
                    'header': checkHeader,
                }
        elif loginData[0]['status'] == 2:
            response = {
                'status': 2,
                'message': 'User is not Registered as a seller',
                'header': checkHeader
            }
        else:
            response = {
                'status': 0,
                'message': 'Login Failed',
                'header': checkHeader
            }
        return JsonResponse(response)
    return Response(serializer.error, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This Runs fine on my localhost(Windows). But gives the following error on ubuntu server.

[image: Postman error]

This is the main error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte.
Please help me

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a django encoding error (utf-8) which I solved using charset and use_unicode option in settings.py

Following is how my settings.py database segment looks

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'NAME': 'testDB',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '123456',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'latin1',
            'use_unicode': True, 
            },
    }
}
```